# Populate an empty CSR sparse matrix with columns of another csr matrix and slicing it

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

(Python)
Can anyone please suggest the easiest and fastest way to populate a csr matrix A with the values from the columns of another csr matrix B which is of size 400k*800k.
My failed attempt:

```
#x is a list of size 500 which contains the column numbers needed from B
A=sparse.csr_matrix((400000,500))

for i in range(400000):
    for j in range(500):
        A[i,j]=B[i,x[j]]
```

Also is there an easy way to split the matrix B in the ratio of 4:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to think about the problem as if `A` and `B` were both dense arrays first. If I understand your question right, you'd want something like:

```
A = B[:, x]
```

It turns out that you can do the same operation with CSR matrices as well, and it's reasonably efficient. The key is to avoid assigning values to an existing sparse matrix (especially if it's in CSR or CSC format). By doing the indexing all at once, scipy is able to use more efficient methods.